# MySql: AUTO_INCREMENT is missing from tables

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

MySql: AUTO_INCREMENT is missing from some tables after running for about one month.

Initially: (show create table Foo)

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

After one month:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

AUTO_INCREMENT is missing. What is the cause?

Mysql Server version: 5.6.25, Linux

Comment: Either a dba or a program removed the auto increment / or the table got restored to a version, which does not have auto increment added to that field. I you have logs, then you may be able to figure it out. If you don't, you will probably never know for sure. What is sure, however, that we cannot tell you what happened there. The bigger question is: what do you plan to do to prevent or at least track such changes to your schema.

Comment: I am the only one who can access the database. I am certain 100% that no one changed the table.

Comment: Look, mysql does no drop auto increment property randomly from fields. If your are the only, who can access the database, then you must have done something that caused this property to drop. Bill Karwin below offers a possible explanation. However, unless you have logs, you will not know for sure.

Comment: Looked at app server log (not db log), at 11am today, user can insert rows into the tables successfully, which means AUTO_INCREMENT was present at that timestamp.

Comment: Many tables. Is there a way to find all the tables from which AUTO_INCREMENT is missing in order to fix them one by one?

Comment: Using information_schema.columns view you can determine which tables do not have an auto increment field. Whether all these tables should have an auto increment field, only you know.

Comment: `SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE AUTO_INCREMENT IS NULL`

Answer (score 3):

Someone must have changed it. This change does not happen spontaneously.

I can reproduce this change myself:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo ( id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, ...

ALTER TABLE Foo MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT;

SHOW CREATE TABLE Foo\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: foo
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now the column shows it is BIGINT but not AUTO_INCREMENT.

Every time you MODIFY COLUMN or CHANGE COLUMN, you must repeat all the column options like NOT NULL and AUTO_INCREMENT and DEFAULT, or else it will revert to defaults (i.e. *not* auto-increment).

So I would interpret this shows that someone did an ALTER TABLE and didn't remember to include the AUTO_INCREMENT column option.

Comment: I am not ready to accept this answer since I am 100% sure we did not alter any tables for the last several months on the production machine. I will see if it will happen again. If it does, mysql will become unusable.

Comment: @Sunnyday I suggest you enable the binary log or the query log now, to capture the statement if it occurs again.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought.

If you have binary logs, you may see the alter query on the logs and when it was run. :)
Check if the binary log is enabled by

```
show variable like 'log_bin';
```

If binary log is enabled, find the likely period that the query could have been executed and then use [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to help you find it.

If binary log is not enabled, bad luck - as the previous post by Bill Karwin has suggested mysql does not change it on its own - someone must have changed it.

Comment: It is OFF, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Happened exactly the same way to me. Not doing any work that involves database changes. No one else with database edit access. Suddenly I have user complaints  AI is turned off for a field it's been running successfully on for seven years/10k inserts. Aurora (AWS clone of MySQL 5.6) not MySQL per SE.

At least this is a management-facing table. Terrified of this happening to a customer transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes happened to me to. Only on my dev machine so not a disaster yet. I think it can do this when the system crashes OR possibly when the machine is simply shut down but MySql has not been shut down first.
It never used to happen *ever*. Maria DB  10.4.27